# function overload of a constant object

Tags: c++, overloading

```
struct A {

    void foo(int i, char& c) { 
        cout << "foo int char&" << endl;
    } 

    void foo(int& i, int j) const {
        cout << "const foo int& int" << endl;
    } 

}; 

int main() {   
    A a;   
    const A const_a;   
    int i = 1;   
    char c = 'a';   
    a.foo(i,i);
}
```

Will be printed:

> const foo int& int

I dont understand why.
Why "const foo int& int" wont be printed?
I thought that constant Object can only call constant methods, and none const can call none const.

Comment: It picks `void foo(int&, int) const` because `int` is the second argument not a `char`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstood member-`const`.

A normal object can have any member function invoked on it, `const` or otherwise.

The constraint is that your `const_a` would not be able to have the non-`const` member function invoked on it. Unfortunately, you did not test that.